# xampp Apache enable proxy for interent operations

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have followd this answer https://serverfault.com/a/249582 to enable proxy and put a line to forward internet operations. However, since I use `http://localhost` to browse my website, it also redirected localhost to the proxy server and thus my website cannot even load.

How can I bypass local addresses such as `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or internal network IP such as `192.168.1.50`, such that `fopensock` can work normally?

Comment: when you set a proxy you can also specify exceptions. Why don't you do that client-side?

Comment: How can I make that?